# Pass extra variable to event C#

Tags: c#, variables, events

Hi first of all i have looked already but didnt seem to get help with this issue.

Basically my application fires an event on data received from a serial port using this:

```
sp.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(sp_DataReceived);
```

And i handle the data received using:

```
private static void sp_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string inData;
        bool passed;
        SerialPort spRead = (SerialPort)sender;
        inData = spRead.ReadLine();
        TwinCat comm = new TwinCat();
        passed = comm.passiButton(inData);
        if (passed) comm.disposeComm();
        else MessageBox.Show("Error Closing Comm");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

In additional to that i have a checkbox control and i would like to pass if checked or not i.e. an extra bool variable so that i can change what to do with the data depending if the checkbox is checked or not.

Note that the conditions are not implemented yet as i cannot pass the bool variable in the event.

Comment: I know i have already seen that post but i cannot figure out how to implement with that information. Can anyone please help me out on my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the `CheckBox` and `SerialPort` are in the same form...

Remove the `static` keyword from the event handler and then access non-GUI variables safely from the `DataReceived` event handler.

```
// member variable
// update the value during the checkbox's CheckChanged event handler
private bool isChecked;

private void sp_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    ...

    if (isChecked) 
    {
        // do something special
    }

    ...
}
```

EDIT: made changes to avoid cross-thread GUI operations

Comment: Now i get a runtime error saying that: Control.Invoke must be used to interact with controls created in a seperate thread.

Comment: Is reading the `Checked` property the only GUI/control operation you need to do?  If it is, I would add a new member variable called `isChecked`, add a `CheckBox.CheckChanged` Event handler, and set the `isChecked` value in that handler.  Then, in this snippet, check: `if (isChecked) { ... }`

Comment: Ok ok i get it i made it and it works fine. THANKS!!